# lemmatizer for Spanish in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

I'm trying to apply lemmatization over some Spanish words in Python 3, I found a nice library "pattern" to do it in python 2. However, this one has no support for python 3 yet and cannot really find a good one. It's not enough for my work to apply a steamer such as SnowBall from nltk. Any help or advice on libraries will be greatly appreciated it.

Comment: Unfortunately, Stack Overflow is not for library suggestions. This is due to the fact that these questions often gather subjective opinions. You're better off googling for this.

Comment: Try `Freeling` http://nlp.lsi.upc.edu/freeling/node/1